# Stacking multiple columns on to one?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google SpreadSheet, and I'm trying to have multiple sheets containg a list of words. On the final sheet, I would like to create a summative list, which is a combination of all the values in the column.  I got it sort working using =CONCATENATE() , but it turned it into a string.  Any way to keep it as a column list?

Here is an example as columns:

**Sheet1**

- apple
- orange
- banana

**Sheet2**

- pineapple
- strawberry
- peach

**FinalSheet**

- apple
- orange
- banana
- pineapple
- strawberry
- peach

Comment: Sounds like a question for web applications instead of stackoverflow

Comment: Forgive me if i am incorrect, but I would need to write a spreadsheet function to get this to work. I would imagine this would be the place for this type of question.

Comment: At this time, you could use embedded arrays. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985637/appending-google-spreadsheet-arrays/15998230#15998230

Comment: I'm slightly confused by something. No where in the question does it say this is looking for *unique* values yet the top answers assume it does. The way it is worded implies that duplicate values should be kept. The question is asking for *'stacking'* columns in a way similar to `CONCATENATE`. If the question is asking for a unique result then this should be made clear in the title and text of the question so people don't visit the page when trying to answer a different problem.

Comment: I wanted to add this as a comment to The Fool's answer, but I don't have enough reputation. "FLATTEN" is now documented. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761 Cheers!

Answer (score 85):

### Updated Answer

I was right there *is* a much better solution. It's been posted below but I'm copying it here so it's in the top answer:

```
=unique({A:A;B:B})
```

*Caveat: This will include one blank cell in certain scenarios (such as if there's one at the end of the first list).*

If you're not concerned with ordering and a tailing blank cell a simple `sort()` will clean things up:

```
=sort(unique({A:A;B:B}))
```

Otherwise a `filter()` can remove the blanks like so:

```
=filter(unique({A:A;B:B}),NOT(ISBLANK(unique({A:A;B:B}))))
```

### The following is the old ***deprecated*** answer

I'm confident that this is "The Wrong Way To Do It", as this seems such an absurdly simple and common task that I feel I must be missing something as it should not require such an overwrought solution.

But this works:

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",A:A,B:B),";")))
```

If your data contains any ';' characters you'll naturally need to change the delimiter.

Comment: It works but there are much simple ways to achieve the desired results. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30039238/1595451

Comment: When I try unique, it puts the data into separate columns instead of merging them in any way, which completely defeats the point.  The "deprecated" answer worked though :/

Comment: Thanks! It works for me.  Merge two columns in Google sheets. Happy Thanksgiving.

Comment: Why bother using unique() at all? The question doesn't say anything about removing duplicates. It looks like you can just remove it.

Comment: The "better" solution doesn't work in Google Sheets, as it does not produce unique results.  The "Deprecated" approach however, works perfectly!

Comment: Deprecated solution works. The "better" solution produces a unique _combination_ of values. That is, it finds unique pairs in columns A and B at the same time. The deprecated method instead is joining the columns together, then finding the unique elements without regard to pairings. The "better" answer might be working for some people when the columns are not adjacent, such as on different sheets, etc.

Comment: The "better" solution worked for me as long as I included each column independently, separated with the semi-colon. I didn't notice that at first.

Comment: Three additional notes. 1. trim() is also handy to remove whitespace 2. sort/unique over a multi-column range e.g. =sort(unique(trim(A2:B143))) in L2 3. after sorting/unique into columns you can show the count of each unique item using countifs() like this: =COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$800, $L$1:$L$800,$B$1:$B$800, $M$1:$M$800)

Comment: nice. is there an excel equivalent for this formula? it doesn't like ;

Comment: Better solution is below: `flatten(A:B)`. This will allow you to input a range of columns without listing each in `{A:A;B:B}`.

Answer (score 14):

The basic way, is just to do it as arrays like so

```
={A1:A10;B1:B10...etc}
```

The problem with this method, as I found out is that its very time consuming if you have lots of columns.
I've done some searching around and have come across this article:

[Joining Multiple Columns Into One Sorted Column in Google Spreadsheets](http://webed.io/2013/11/04/joining-multiple-columns-one-sorted-column-google-spreadsheets/)

The core formula is

```
=transpose(split(arrayformula(concatenate(if(len(A:Z)>0,A:Z&";",""))),";"))
```

Obviously you'd replace the A:Z to whatever range you want to use. 
And if you want to do some sorting or removing duplicates, you'd simply wrap the the above formula in a `SORT()` and/or `UNIQUE()` method, like so..

```
=sort(unique(transpose(split(arrayformula(concatenate(if(len(A:Z)>0,A:Z&";",""))),";"))))
```

Hope this helps.
Happy coding everyone :)

Comment: It should be noted that this concatenates all values with a ; into one big string, and then splits them by a ; again to create the final array (=column). This will break (subtly) if any of the cells contain a ; themselves. If that's the case, change the two occurrences of ; in this snippet to a different character, e.g. § or * or anything that doesn't exist in your data. If you don't, what will happen is a cell like "a;b" becomes two separate cells in the final, big column; "a" and "b". This can cause delicate bugs :)

Comment: This doesn't deal with an array on two sheets. If you have the range in once piece you can save yourself the whole function there and call flatten.  With you snippet you had to  type out all ranges even twice. https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/flatten-function-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
=unique({A1:A;B1:B})
```

Works perfect here!

Comment: This seems to give an error if the given column ranges are not the same shape.

Comment: is there an excel equivalent for this? it doesn't accept ;

Answer (score 8):

The `unique()` function gets rid of blank spaces, but wasn't helpful for me because some of my rows repeat. Instead I first filter the columns by `len()` to remove blank cells. Then I combine the columns together in the same way.

`={filter(A:A, len(A:A)); filter(B:B, len(B:B))}`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`flatten`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761), e.g. `flatten(A1:B2)`. More details in [this article](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/flatten-function-in-google-sheets/).

If the 2d range is not in one piece, one can be created first with the ampersand or similar techniques. Afterwards flatten can be called on the resulting 2d range. The below example is a bit overkill but it is nice when working with dynamic 2d ranges, where the basic solution can't be easily used.

```
flatten(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A2&";"&C3:C4), ";")))
```

The article shows also how to easily *unflatten* a range using the, as well undocumented, `skipping` clause in a query.

Comment: Underappreciated answer. I was looking to have the rows merge in an alternating zip-kind-of fashion, and this did the trick super easily. Thanks!

Comment: [deadneck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14826917) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66535318) saying "I wanted to add this as a comment to The Fool's answer, but I don't have enough reputation."FLATTEN" is now documented.https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761"

Answer (score 5):

Much more simple:

```
={sheetone!A2:A;sheettwo!A2:A}
```

Comment: This formula also include all the blank cells in the column.

Comment: This gives an error if the sheets have a different number of rows

Answer (score 1):

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(A:C),TRANSPOSE(D1:D5)),"@",FALSE,FALSE))`

- use a preferred delimiter absent in the data (instead of `@`) if needed
- the first `1` (`TRUE`) parameter means **IGNORE EMPTY**, which is very important in this case..
- the `A:C` and `D1:D5` are the ranges to combine
- all values remain there - not using `UNIQUE`

Answer (score -4):

Try using your CONCATENATE argument with

```
=ArrayFormula(EXPAND(...))
```