# Combining three columns in google spreadsheets into one with no duplicates

Tags: merge, google-sheets

I have three columns containing different breeds of dogs (the list is much more extensive):

```
Border Collie           Beagle       German Shepard
Australian Sheepdog     Husky        Australian Sheepdog
```

I want the result to be just the list of the breeds in one column (in a new sheet), without duplicates:

```
Border Collie
Australian Sheepdog
Beagle
Husky
German Shepard
```

I have tried `=UNIQUE(DogBreeds_)` but it gives them in three columns still. 
`DogBreeds_` being the macro for the three columns of all the breeds.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=unique(transpose(split(join(";",A1:A2,B1:B2,C1:C2),";")))
```

Assuming that your data is in the first two rows of the columns A,B,C

I'm sure that there must be a prettier solution, but that's the only one that came to my mind.
Actually, this seems a duplicate to this problem: [Stacking multiple columns on to one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442099/stacking-multiple-columns-on-to-one)

Hope it helps.