# Gather values from a range to a single column?

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know how to gather values from a range to a single column?
for exempele...
i have information in cells A1:C5
and I want those cell to be copied to Column H (H1, H2 and so on....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is pretty much answered here: [Stacking multiple columns on to one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442099/stacking-multiple-columns-on-to-one)

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",A:A,B:B,C:C),";"))
```

Note that you could equally well just do from row 1 through 5 like this:

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",A1:A5,B1:B5,C1:C5),";")))
```

As mentionned by Adam, this will work with the new Google Docs, and is more simple:

```
={A1:A5;B1:B5;C1:C5}
```

Comment: wow man, you're awsome. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

From the same question Jonathan linked to, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454956/1373663) is now the better one (it is supported in the newest version of Sheets, which wasn't around when that question was first asked).

`={A1:A5;B1:B5;C1:C5}`