# Excel, append one range to the end of another in one column

Tags: excel

I have two columns of data in Excel. I would like to add a third column which combines the first and second. How can I do this with a formula such that I can add or remove data from columns A and B without ever having to touch column C?

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
Bob       Mary      Bob
Joe       Melissa   Joe
Jim       Jackie    Jim
                    Mary
                    Melissa
                    Jackie
```

Answer (score 2):

The question explicit mention [Microsoft Office Excel](https://products.office.com/en-gb/excel) but I think would be good to add that if you are using [Google Sheets](https://www.google.co.uk/sheets/about/) a simpler solution is to use the curly brackets function/operator as mentioned by [Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180070/lake) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151000/1802726.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution using FILTERXML and TEXTJOIN that can append **MULTIPLE RANGES OF ANY SIZE, ARRAY FORMULAS AND REGULAR FORMULAS**. Just replace ***YOUR_RANGES*** with the ranges or dynamic arrays you wish to join:

---

**Simple version that ignores empty cells:**

```
=FILTERXML("<A><B>" & TEXTJOIN("</B><B>",TRUE,YOUR_RANGES) & "</B></A>", "//B")
```

---

**This one includes empty cells:**

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<A><B>" & TEXTJOIN("</B><B>",FALSE,YOUR_RANGE) & "</B></A>", "//B"), "")
```

---

**If your input data contains the "<" character, the formulas above will return an error, so use this one instead:**

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<A><B>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("ΨΨ",FALSE,YOUR_RANGE),"<","ЉЉ"),"ΨΨ","</B><B>")&"</B></A>","//B"),"ЉЉ","<"),"")
```

Note: you can change the FALSE to TRUE to ignore empty cells.

Note 2: You can replace the characters **ЉЉ** and **ΨΨ** by any character(s). I used these specific characters because it is very unlikely that your input data will contain ЉЉ or ΨΨ, which would cause errors.

---

### NOTES:

Tested on:

- Excel 365

---

### EXAMPLE:

[image]

Using the simple version of the formula:

```
=FILTERXML("<A><B>" & TEXTJOIN("</B><B>",TRUE,A1:A3,B1:B3,C1:C3) & "</B></A>", "//B")
```

As a result you will get a dynamic array with the joined/appended ranges:

[image]

You can then apply any dynamic array formula (like UNIQUE) to the result.

---

### HOW THIS WORKS:

The JOINTEXT function grabs your ranges and joins them as a text with the delimiter **"</ B >< B >"**. Then, after adding "< A >< B >" to the beginning and "</ B ></ A >" to the end, we have an XML formatted text:

```
<A><B>1</B><B>2</B><B>3</B><B>A</B><B>B</B><B>C</B><B>!</B><B>@</B><B>#</B></A>
```

Finally, the FILTERXML will separate the  tags into a dynamic array which will be the joined/appended ranges.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is old but I had this problem today. Use [VSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c).

For the original question:

```
=VSTACK(A1:A3,B1:B3)
```

Hope that saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula into cell C1

```
=IF(ROW()>COUNTA(A:B),"",IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),INDEX(A:A,ROW()),INDEX(B:B,ROW()-COUNTA(B:B))))
```

Then copy down as far as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice way of interleaving the two rows.

In other words, turning this:

```
A  X
B  Y
C  Z
```

into this:

```
X
A
Y
B
Z
C
```

Say the above table is in columns one and two, you'd do:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INT(ROW()/2), 1)), 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INT(ROW()/2)+1, 2)))
```

---

### Explanation

Let's break that down a little. The first part is `MOD(ROW(), 2)` which returns a zero if the current row is even, and a one if  it's odd.

So the `IF` goes `FALSE/TRUE/FALSE/TRUE` as we go down the column.

Next, the `ADDRESS(INT(ROW()/2), 1)` returns us a string representation of the address of the cell at column 1 and at half the current row. (Rounded down). This piece on its own looks like:

```
#VALUE!
$A$1
$A$1
$A$2
$A$2
$A$3
$A$3
```

*(That first `#VALUE` error is because 1/2 = 0.5 which rounds down to zero. There's no row zero!)*

The `INDIRECT` function returns whatever value is found at that address.

The rest is pretty clear.

NOTE: There may be a slicker way than using `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS`. Suggestions welcome.