# Consolidate (Append) two dynamic array formulas in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, dynamic-arrays

How to combine two dynamic array formula (like filter functions) one below another?

```
=FILTER(A5:B14,A5:A14>5)
=FILTER(Sheet2!A5:B14,Sheet2!A5:A14>8)
```

I want the results to come one below another irrespective of number of rows picked up.  Is it possible ?

Comment: [Might be useful](https://exceljet.net/formula/lambda-append-range). Combining (appending) ranges isn't very straightforward unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently Office365 introduced two functions HSTACK and VSTACK.  We can use VSTACK function for this requirement.

```
 =VSTACK(FILTER(A5:B14,A5:A14>5),FILTER(Sheet2!A5:B14,Sheet2!A5:A14>8))
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very easy too achieve unfortunately. I guess one could try use `LAMBDA()` but it can also be achieved using `FILTERXML()` and `TEXTJOIN()` when these `FILTER()` is applied as per your example:

[image]

Formula in `G5`:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,FILTER(A5:B14,B5:B14>5,""),FILTER(D5:E14,E5:E14>5,""))&"</s></t>","//s"),INDEX(X,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X)/2,2)))
```

I used `LET()` but I guess you could also add two `COUNTIFS()` instead.

Comment: Super... Works Great... However my version of Excel still does not support LET().  But I just adjusted the countifs... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291654/excel-append-one-range-to-the-end-of-another-in-one-column/72454134#72454134), you join miltiple ranges or dynamic array formulas with this formula, replacing **YOUR_RANGES** with the ranges or formulas you wish to join:

```
=FILTERXML("<A><B>" & TEXTJOIN("</B><B>",TRUE,YOUR_RANGES) & "</B></A>", "//B")
```

In your case, you can split the filter to get only column A in the first result column, and only column B for the second result column:

RESULT SHEET A1 CELL:

```
=FILTERXML("<A><B>" & TEXTJOIN("</B><B>",TRUE, FILTER(A5:A14,$A5:$A14>5); FILTER(Sheet2!A5:A14,Sheet2!$A5:$A14>8) ) & "</B></A>", "//B")
```

RESULT SHEET B1 CELL:

```
=FILTERXML("<A><B>" & TEXTJOIN("</B><B>",TRUE, FILTER(B5:B14,$A5:$A14>5); FILTER(Sheet2!B5:B14,Sheet2!$A5:$A14>8) ) & "</B></A>", "//B")
```

This will join the 2 filters, one beneath the other, although each column will have a separate dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

Found an excellent answer (it was also provided as a comment to the question, but I believe it merits being a full answer) in the form of a lambda UDF by Dave Burns at ExcelJet: https://exceljet.net/formula/lambda-append-range

```
=LAMBDA(range1,range2,default,
  LET(
  rows1,ROWS(range1),
  rows2,ROWS(range2),
  cols1,COLUMNS(range1),
  cols2,COLUMNS(range2),
  rowindex,SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),
  colindex,SEQUENCE(1,MAX(cols1,cols2)),
  result,
  IF(
    rowindex<=rows1,
    INDEX(range1,rowindex,colindex),
    INDEX(range2,rowindex-rows1,colindex)
  ),
  IFERROR(result,default)
  )
)
```