# Stack multiple columns into one

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want to do a simple task but somehow I'm unable to do it. Assume that I have one column like:

```
a
z
e
r
t
```

How can I create a new column with the same value twice with the following result:

```
a
a
z
z
e
e
r
r
t
t
```

I've already tried to double my column and do something like :

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",A:A,B:B),";"))
```

but it creates:

```
a
z
e
r
t
a
z
e
r
t
```

I get inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442099/stacking-multiple-columns-on-to-one/30039238#30039238) so far.

Comment: how about copying the data, pasting it twice to another column and then sorting?

Comment: Yes sure but I have few hundreds rows... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`=SORT({A1:A5;A1:A5})`

Here we use:

- [sort](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [{}](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) to combine data

---

Accounting your comment, then you may use this formula:

`=QUERY(SORT(ArrayFormula({row(A1:A5),A1:A5;row(A1:A5),A1:A5})),"select Col2")`

The idea is to use additional column of data with number of row, then sort by row, then [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to get only values.

---

And [join](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)→[split](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) method will do the same:
`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(A1:A5&",",A1:A5))),","))`

Here we use range only two times, so this is easier to use. Also see [Concat + ArrayFormula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54645/concatenate-a-string-with-an-arrayformula) sample.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it to be sorted it can be 3;3;1;1;2;2;4;4;5;5 for example

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! Didn't thought it would be such a complicated formula for this kind of task. Thanks!!! Saved me a lot of copy/paste

Comment: Thanks. There's another way to accomplish this. I've made one more update.

Answer (score 1):

Few hundreds rows is nothing :)

I created index from 1 to n, then pasted it twice and sorted by index. But it's obviously fancier to do it with a formula :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Your list is in column A and (for now) the times of repeat are in C1 (can be changed to a number in the formula), then something simple like this will do (starting in B1):

```
=INDEX(A:A,(INT(ROW()-1)/$C$1)+1)
```

Simply copy down as you need it (will give just 0 after the last item). No sorting. No array. No sheets/excel problems. No heavy calculations.