# Google spreadsheet, append the first columns of all sheets into one new column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with multiple tabs. I would like to append all the element of the first columns of all tabs into one new column. How can I do this with a formula such that I can add or remove data from first columns, and also, add tabs without ever having to touch my new column?

```
Sheet 1 Column A    Sheet 2 Column A    New Column
Bob                 Mary                Bob
Joe                 Melissa             Joe
Jim                 Jackie              Jim
                                        Mary
                                        Melissa
                                        Jackie
```

Comment: I can't imagine any reasonable way to do this without scripting.

Comment: @JNevill Can you run scripts in google spreadsheet?

Comment: [More info here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442099/stacking-multiple-columns-on-to-one . Long story short =filter(unique({Sheet1!A:A ; Sheet2!A:A}),NOT(ISBLANK(unique({Sheet1!A:A; Sheet2!A:A}))))

Answer (score 0):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

`=query({'Sheet1'!A:A;'Sheet2'!A:A}, "select * where Col1 <> ''")`

Please see more info on arrays {} [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en), and about `query` funcrion [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

You'll probably need to use some VBA code for this.