# Stacking variable number of ranges from other sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a number of sheets in my Google Sheets Doc.
I would like to stack some rows from most of the sheets in another sheet.

Here is the code I am using:

```
=VSTACK(
   MAP(
     {"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"; "E"},
   LAMBDA(
     sheetname,    
     FILTER(
       INDIRECT(
         "'"&sheetname&"'!A1:A10"),
       INDIRECT(
         "'"&sheetname&"'!A1:A10")<>2)
     )
   )
)
```

This code, however, returns "Result should be a single row." error. Each lambda maps the name of the sheet to the range of rows. The question now is, how can I stack all of those ranges into one big table?

[Reproducible sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ztU4jqqMyQqdZ5TaK9iIQPoFBvxAW6Zl-bt4pX_Acto/edit?usp=sharing)

It's easy to stack a predefined number of ranges ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287145/2333458)) but how could one stack the variable number of ranges that are returned from the `MAP` function? The length of my array is static in the example for simplicity but in reality it's variable and the array is returned by a function.

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: `REDUCE()` function may help. You need to specify sheet name in a range or inside function. Then use `FILTER()` function and store the results to accumulator of `REDUCE()` function.

Comment: Is `sheetnames()` a custom formula? Note: you are missing a right parenthesis somewhere in there.

Comment: @Harun24hr, could you let me know how to reduce two ranges into one? I tried this `=REDUCE({}, 
   MAP(
     {"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"; "E"},
   LAMBDA(
     sheetname,    
     FILTER(
       INDIRECT(
         "'"&sheetname&"'!A1:A10"),
       INDIRECT(
         "'"&sheetname&"'!A1:A10")<>2)
     )
   ),
LAMBDA(x, y, {x;y}))` but it did not work

Comment: @horanimal Yes, `sheetnames()` is a custom formula returning all the names of the sheets in the given doc. I don't think any parenthesis were missing but anyway, with the link to reproducible sample anyone can play around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,reduce(,tocol(F:F,1),lambda(a,c,{a;indirect("'"&c&"'!A1:A10")})),
       filter(Σ,Σ<>2,Σ<>""))
```

- tab names are listed in `Column_F` here

[image]

***Updated answer***:

```
=let(Σ,reduce(wraprows(,2,),tocol(F:F,1),lambda(a,c,{a;indirect("'"&c&"'!A1:B10")})),
       filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>2,index(Σ,,1)<>""))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for a single column, however, I have multiple columns in my sheets I want to aggregate data from. If I specify the range as "A1:B10", I get the following error: "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.". Any ideas?

Comment: Try the updated answer to  take into account `2` columns. Change the number within `wraprows` part to equal the number of columns your are importing from other tabs...